# OrientDB row count

Tags: java, orientdb

How to get specific row count in Java from Object DB ?

I need to get result for query like : 
`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Users WHERE banned=true`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using * as field:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Users WHERE banned = false`

Comment: int total = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Users WHERE banned = false")).get(0).field("count");

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB does support **SQL like queries** and also supports the `count(<field>|*)` function according to the documentation: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/SQLWhere#Functions

Comment: I can't get count as long in easy way, I use something like this : 

`List<ODocument> list = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>("SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM Users WHERE banned = false"));
return list.get(0).field("count");`

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to fetch this easier.